# Using two Select statements in one query to bring back desired data set

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help in correcting this query.

I am trying to bring back the TRADE_AMT for the last week (w1) and then for the year (YTD). But the query keeps failing, I know there is a simpler solution but that is not I am looking for as I would like to learn this idea of using multiple select statements to bring back one data set as per the very first Select statement.

Also, I would like to group by login IDs but I know I can have only one from statement.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT login, W1.TRADE_AMT, YTD.TRADE_AMT
FROM 
(SELECT sum(TRADE_AMT) FROM CORPS
    WHERE DATE > 20180903 AND DATE_ID <= 20180910 
    AND REGION = 'London'
    AND Rating = 'High'
    AND LOGIN IN ('ITI1','RAB0','RR12') ) AS W1

UNION ALL

(SELECT sum(TRADE_AMT) FROM CORPS
    WHERE DATE > 20180101 AND DATE_ID < 20180911 
    AND REGION = 'London'
    AND Rating = 'High'
    AND LOGIN IN ('ITI1','RAB0','RR12') ) AS YTD


GROUP BY login
```

Sample Date From Corps Table:

```
Login   Trade_AMT   Date    Rating
ITI1    100   20180509    High
RAB0    150   20180910    High
RR12    25    20180104    High
YTRT    100   20180225    Low
ACE1    123   20180908    Low
ITI1    354   20180903    Low
RAB0    254   20180331    High
RR12    245   20180314    High
RR12    5236  20180505    High
```

Desired Result:

```
Login       W1_Volume   YTD_Volume
ITI1        100         2000
RAB0        150         2500
RR12        25          3000
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a database tag would all really help.

Comment: You only select `sum(TRADE_AMT)` in the subqueries. So you cannot possibly access any `login` or `TRADE_AMT` from them. `UNION ALL` takes rows from two queries, so you have more *rows*. With `select w1.trade_amt, ydt.trade_amt` your are accssing *columns*, so you'd need a join.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: @Ali_M your condition and desired output does not match because last week ITI1 value will be null because you use >2018-09-03 but value on that day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could be using  an inner join  on subquery group by login

```
    SELECT W1.login, W1.TRADE_AMT, YTD.TRADE_AMT
    FROM 
    (SELECT login, sum(TRADE_AMT) AS TRADE_AMT FROM CORPS
        WHERE DATE > 20180903 AND DATE_ID <= 20180910 
        AND REGION = 'London'
        AND Rating = 'High'
        AND LOGIN IN ('ITI1','RAB0','RR12') 
      GROUP BY LOGIN) AS W1
    LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT login, sum(TRADE_AMT) AS TRADE_AMT FROM CORPS
    WHERE DATE > 20180101 AND DATE_ID < 20180911 
        AND REGION = 'London'
        AND Rating = 'High'
        AND LOGIN IN ('ITI1','RAB0','RR12') 
        GROUP BY LOGIN ) AS YTD ON YTD.LOGIN =  W1.LOGIN
```

left join show also not matching login values but you can use inner join if you need oly matching login between week and year

Comment: Maybe you should better outer join week data to the year data, so as not to lose rows.

Comment: Sorry can you please check third select statement?

Comment: Also, should be AS before YTD when naming the dataset as table?

Comment: @Ali_M  .. thanks  .. editing the answer  a part of code was  deleted .. many thanks for notify ..me   ..

Comment: Also, using this answer, I don;t get the login in the result set "says ambigous column name" - any ideas pls?

Comment: @Ali_M: "ambigous" means ambigous. There are two `login`, `w1.login`  and `ytd.login`. So you cannot merely `SELECT login`.

Comment: @scaisEdge: You have the outer join upside down and you are missing a qualifier for the login column you are selecting.

Comment: @Ali_M  .. answer  updated .. login was in both the tables so just added the table alias .. for avoid ambiguity

Answer (score 1):

According to sample i got that you need `min()` of TRADE_AMT for 1st sub-query but not got the 2nd sub-query aggregate function properly

```
SELECT login, W1.TRADE_AMT, YTD.TRADE_AMT
FROM 
(SELECT login,min(TRADE_AMT) as TRADE_AMT  FROM CORPS
    WHERE DATE > '20180903' AND DATE_ID <= '20180910' 
    AND REGION = 'London'
    AND Rating = 'High'
    AND LOGIN IN ('ITI1','RAB0','RR12') 
 group by login) AS W1

  join

(SELECT login, sum(TRADE_AMT) as TRADE_AMT FROM CORPS
    WHERE DATE > '20180101' AND DATE_ID < '20180911' 
    AND REGION = 'London'
    AND Rating = 'High'
    AND LOGIN IN ('ITI1','RAB0','RR12') 
    group by login
 ) AS YTD
on W1.login=YTD.login
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `case` expressions to do conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT login,
       sum(case when DATE > 20180903 AND DATE_ID <= 20180910 then TRADE_AMT end) W1_Volume, 
       sum(case when DATE > 20180101 AND DATE_ID < 20180911 then TRADE_AMT end) YTD_Volume
FROM CORPS
WHERE REGION = 'London'
  AND Rating = 'High'
  AND LOGIN IN ('ITI1','RAB0','RR12')
GROUP BY login
```

Optionally you can put back a date condition to the `WHERE` clause to speed things up:

```
  AND DATE > 20180101 AND DATE_ID < 20180911
```

Answer (score 1):

Bottom line is your outer query can't be selective (W1.something, YTD.something), from the inner queries when you put them together with a union. They get melded into a single result set. When you union, you have to leave "clues" in the result set to figure why the rows are interesting:

```
SELECT [login], TRADE_AMT, amt_type
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    [login], sum(TRADE_AMT), 'week' as amt_type
  FROM 
    CORPS
  WHERE 
     DATE > 20180903 AND DATE_ID <= 20180910 
     AND REGION = 'London'
     AND Rating = 'High'
     AND [LOGIN] IN ('ITI1','RAB0','RR12') 
  group by 
    [login]

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 
    [login], sum(TRADE_AMT), 'ytd' as amt_type
  FROM 
    CORPS
  WHERE 
    DATE > 20180101 AND DATE_ID < 20180911 
    AND REGION = 'London'
    AND Rating = 'High'
    AND [LOGIN] IN ('ITI1','RAB0','RR12') 
  group by 
    [login]
)
```

...where the amt_type indicates whether it was from the ytd query or the week query.

That's the issue with union queries. You can pivot the result set, but that's unnecessary...unless you just need the results in a particular format. It depends on the code consuming the result set.

(Also - LOGIN is a reserved word...probably ought to bracket it where you don't mean the reserved word)

You can get your result sets on one-line-per-login with a join (rather than a union), as per scaisEdge answer, but I assumed you were trying to figure out the union approach.